# Insert value of dynamically created radiobuttonlist in database through programming

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

> I am trying to bind radiobutton list dynamically in programm. But I do
>   not know how to insert value.
>
> Aspx Page code

```
<asp:Table ID="tblSponser" runat="server"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" Visible="false"></asp:Table>
```

> on dropdownlist selectedindex event I am Binding Radio Button in Code
>   behind

```
  Protected Sub ddlVotes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlVotes.SelectedIndexChanged

    For SponserId = 0 To sponserDtst.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim tr As New TableRow
                    Dim c1 As New TableCell
                    Dim c2 As New TableCell

    Dim rbtyes As New RadioButtonList

                    rbtyes.ID = "rbtypes" & SponserId
                    rbtyes.ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static
                    rbtyes.Items.Add(New ListItem("Yes"))
                    rbtyes.Items.Add(New ListItem("No"))
                    rbtyes.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
                    c2.Controls.Add(rbtyes)
    c2.Controls.Add(rbtyes)
                    tr.Controls.Add(c1)
                    tr.Controls.Add(c2)
                    tblSponser.Controls.Add(tr)
```

> Below code is not working. How to get value of radiobuttonlist and
>   store in database on button click event.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmitVote_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitVote.Click

    Dim i As Integer
            Dim x As Integer = 5
            For i = 0 To x - 1
                Dim str As String = "rbtypes" & i
                Dim rb As RadioButtonList = CType(tblSponser.FindControl(str), RadioButtonList)
                Dim ix As String = rb.SelectedValue
            Next
```

Comment: This code is working for me. Are you trying to get the values of the RadioButtons while the Table's visible property equals false?

Comment: Dim rb As RadioButtonList = CType(tblSponser.FindControl(str), RadioButtonList) rb value is nothing. so basically it does not find control.

Comment: I am asking you if the control is visible... I am able to find the radio buttons.

Comment: yes control is visible. please help me

Comment: when i click on button page is getting refresh. may be because of that reason i am not getting value of radio button

Comment: Yes, a postback will occur, but you should still be able to see. Do you have a If Not Page.IsPostBack in your Page_Load where you create the buttons dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

At which point in the page load process do you execute your code? You should be doing this in OnInit method in order to work properly. 
Take a look at this – it provides a good info on asp.net page life cycle

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)